# Angular 2 - always redirect to https:// instead of using http://

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app that I only want to run on https.
What is the best way to redirect addresses that use http to use https instead?

Comment: Where is your App hosted?

Comment: Its in Azure as a web application.

Comment: Are you using Apache Linux or some thing else?

Comment: IIS I believe is the default in Azure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added a web.config to the Angular2 site which contains the below. Remember that this is for an IIS hosted application.
All addresses are now redirected the https version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where are you placing this file?

Comment: In at root of the website when on iis.

Comment: OK. It wasn't working because I didn't have URL rewrite installed on my server. After getting it installed in combination with this rule it was working. Thanks.

Comment: I have similar situation but for me the application is created through Angular -cli. so I cannot this file explicitly. And Azure is the server in my case. Any solution?

Comment: Could you copy the file as part of your build process?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you will have to force https for you domain from the server side. As you mentioned IIS in your comment here are some of the ways that you can achieve force HTTps.

https://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

Answer (score 0):

I have to write in an exception rule for the web api service based on where the web api was located within same area  :/

Notice this line

```
  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(C2NGService)" negate="true" />
```

web.config for angular 5

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(C2NGService)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```