# Angular automatically changes the http to https to load resource

Tags: angular, angular-http

In my angular app, all the HTTP resources are automatically changed to https while fetching. I checked the server, and there are no automatic redirect settings configured to https.

The following are the errors I get in the console and the network tab.

```
core.js:3864 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://xxxxxx-env.eba-prmacaby.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/all/hub/", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://xxxxx-env.eba-prmacaby.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/all/hub/: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://xxxxxx-env.eba-prmacaby.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/all/hub/"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

[image]

[image]
In the console it says HTTP but in the network tab, it says HTTPS.

Request Code

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
     
 getHub( ): Observable<Hub> {
       
        return this.http.get<Hub>("http://xxxxxxxx-env.eba-prmacaby.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/all/hub" );
      }
```

Comment: Can't see screenshots, could you please share error messages as text?

Comment: @shadowman_93 I edited the description with error text from the console.

Comment: Please check you IIS configuration, do you have configuretion like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38686154/5955138

Comment: No, I don't have any such configs

Comment: Add your request code here, i cannot help you without some code.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi I edited the description with request code. Please have a look

Comment: That it a bad idead direkt to call the api like that.
Try Postman and try to get request with it if you have the same error.
If is the same error than something in the api it is not correct.
If there works then u need to check your code in FE.

Comment: The API is working fine. I have verified it from the postman. The code isn't that complex. Just stared only with a new project.

Answer (score 0):

```
getHub(): Observable<Hub> {  
  return this.http.get<Hub>("http://xxxxxxxx-env.eba-prmacaby.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/all/hub" ).subscribe(test => console.log(test));
  }
```

Try it and show what are u  expecting.

Comment: It can't subscribe to the response as it fails due to the https on the URL. I subscribed to the error state and the exception is given below. It is the same as the exception I see on the browser

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http:// xxxx-env.eba-prmacaby.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/all/hub/", ok: false, …}

Comment: Have you added the HttpClientModule in the `app.module.ts`

Comment: Yes, there is no exception related to the code. My other HTTPS resources are loading fine.

Comment: Try to remove the `Observable` and write a pure method.
`getHub() {  
  return this.http.get("http://xxxxxxxx-env.eba-prmacaby.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/all/hub");
  }`

Look if it works and remove the white space at the end of the `all/hub` because u have a space there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your CSP there if you have "upgrade-insecure-requests" you are upgrading your http requests to https requests.

Do not use following content attribute:-

meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"